# Remove all rows above and below a value in R

Tags: r, rows

We have citizen scientist recording data for us using In-Situ Aqua troll 600 instruments. It is similar to a CTD but not. The data format is a little different. Different enough that I cannot use CTD trim from the OCE package in R. I need to remove all the rows of data during the soak time (time in the water before they start lowering the instrument) and the up cast from the data. That is all the rows after they reached the max depth. So I just need that center portion of my dataframe.
**My Data**

```
Date Time   Salinity (ppt) (672441) Chlorophyll-a Fluorescence (RFU) (671721)   RDO Concentration (mg/L) (672144)   Temperature (°C) (676121)   Depth (ft) (671051)
16:29.0 0   0.01089297  7.257619    31.91303    0.008220486
16:31.0 0   0.01765913  7.246986    31.93175    0.1499496
16:33.0 0   0.0130412   7.258863    31.93253    0.5387784
16:35.0 0   0.01299242  7.274049    31.93806    0.6187978
16:37.0 0   0.01429801  7.26965 31.94401    0.6640261
16:39.0 0   0.01342988  7.271608    31.93595    0.681709
16:41.0 0   0.01337719  7.271549    31.93503    0.684597
16:43.0 7.087267    0.007094439 6.98015 31.89018    1.598019
16:45.0 28.3442 0.007111916 6.268753    31.83806    1.687673
16:47.0 31.06357    0.007945394 6.197834    31.77821    1.418773
16:49.0 32.07076    0.0080788   6.166986    31.76881    1.382685
16:51.0 31.95504    0.004382414 6.191305    31.72906    1.358556
16:53.0 36.21165    0.01983912  5.732656    29.3942 123.4148
16:55.0 36.37849    0.02243886  5.626586    28.82502    125.2927
16:57.0 36.43061    0.02416219  5.450325    28.23787    126.7997
16:59.0 36.44484    0.02441683  5.421676    28.14037    127.0321
17:01.0 36.46815    4.510316    5.318929    28.09501    127.2064
17:03.0 36.41381    4.012657    5.241654    28.14595    127.2227
17:05.0 36.42724    0.7891375   5.174401    28.20383    127.2019
17:07.0 36.41064    0.4351442   5.120181    28.18592    127.197
17:09.0 36.38155    0.2253969   5.033384    28.21021    127.1895
17:11.0 36.37671    0.2089337   5.019629    28.21222    127.1885
17:13.0 36.43813    0.08728585  4.981099    28.17526    127.2223
17:15.0 36.47644    0.904435    4.951878    28.13579    127.2108
17:17.0 36.54742    0.1230291   4.93056 28.06166    127.2307
17:19.0 36.60466    10.04291    4.908442    27.9397 126.6003
17:21.0 36.61511    11.33922    4.904828    27.92038    126.5161
17:23.0 36.68179    0.6680982   4.87018 27.78319    123.707
17:25.0 36.74612    0.06539913  4.848994    27.72977    119.906
17:27.0 36.75729    0.02414635  4.826871    27.72545    114.9537
17:29.0 37.1578 0.01556828  4.804105    27.81129    113.3405



> depthmax<- max(WS$`Depth (ft) (671051)`, na.rm = TRUE)
> output <- WS[WS$"Depth (ft) (671051)" < depthmax,]
> Output2 <- output[output$"Depth (ft) (671051)" > 1,]
```

I tried these and got output2 to work but can't seam to get output to work. Is there a more elegant way to do this? Just to recap I need to remove all rows after the depthmax (127.2307) and all the rows before  the depth when they start lowering the instrument (~2.41).

Comment: Sorry for the terrible way this looks. Can someone tell me how to post a data table to this site?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how to make a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does remove the maximum depth, but not the rows after the maximum depth is reached. You want to locate the row index of the the maximum depth and delete that row and the ones after:

```
start <- tail(which(na.omit(WS$`Depth (ft) (671051)`) < 2.41), 1) + 1
end<- which.max(na.omit(WS$`Depth (ft) (671051)`)) - 1
output <- WS[start:end, ]
```

The first line finds the index of the last row less than 2.41 and adds 1 to get the starting row. The second line finds the index of the maximum depth and subtracts 1 to get the row before that.

Comment: Thanks that does the trick. I need the max depth so commented out the -1 at the end of the second line.